# Find URL scheme

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to check whether the incoming url having http or https in c#? Is there any default method to find the url scheme(http/https)?

Answer (score 5):

You could use Uri.Scheme to check and see if it is https.

You could also just use [`Request.IsSecureConnection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.issecureconnection.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

```
var currentUrl = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Url;
if (!currentUrl.Scheme.Equals(Uri.UriSchemeHttps, 
    StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
```

For more information : [Uri.UriSchemeHttps Field](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.urischemehttps.aspx)